# Crontab with php exec

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to make this work :

```
exec("crontab -u root -l", $crons, $return);
```

But `$crons` returns an empty array even tho the command works and when I run `sudo crontab -u root -l` it gives me a result looking like this :

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
*/1   * * * *   root     /usr/bin/php /var/www/console Test:Testing
```

The last line is the one that is important I think...

Why am I getting an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its because php user is not privileged to use -u ,
and you cannot use sudo in exec, because you must enter the root password

you can edit visudo and add

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab`

www-data is the user under which php is running,
and change your code to

`exec("sudocrontab -u root -l", $crons, $return);`

but in this case all php scripts will have access to root users crontab

[image]

Comment: What is `visudo`? Also I don't want to make every command run in sudo for the user root, just the crontab one :)

Comment: So I followed your advice but it still doesn't work.

Comment: when you add this line to visudo you grant access only to crontab , but every other script can access and change root users crontab, thats why i don't recommend using this

Comment: do you added sudo before crontab -uroot ?

Comment: Yes, but in my knowledge `exec()` doesn't use sudo :)

Comment: it works for me , check screenshot that i attached to my post